# Search outside of the "loop"

Tags: search

I am creating a blog using only Wordpress's backend. I have found functions to get latest posts (wp_get_recent_posts) and all the required data I need. I do this by including wp-load so I have access to WP's functions.

However I cannot find anything that allows me to perform a search outside of Wordpress's theming loops as I have for the rest of the data.

I was hoping there was a search function where I can pass it a search query that could be in title, body content or tag name.

Am I missing something blindingly obvious in the documentation, there seems to be a function for everything else I need outside of WP's "loop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_posts()` with a search parameter:

```
$results = get_posts( array( 's' => 'search term' ) );
```

Comment: It's also worth adding 'numberposts' => -1 otherwise it falls back to the default of max 5 posts.

It doesn't seem to search tags, but good enough

Comment: Good shout. You can pass in anything you would pass into WP_Query but the `s` param has the effect of search all post types unless specified - also worth noting.