# Get post count for search result based on post type

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I am trying to display the search result based on custom post type in sections. and if no search result for post type I do not want to display that section label . here the problem with this code is $post_query in custom_has_posts() function, the query containing all the post types instead of the one I have passed in function call .

search.php page

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php $post_types = get_post_types(array('public' => true, 'exclude_from_search' => false), 'objects'); ?>
        <?php foreach( $post_types as $post_type ): ?>
              <?php if ( !in_array($post_type->name, array('page', 'menu', 'nav_menu_item', 'custom_css', 'customize_changeset', 'revision') ) ): ?>
              <div class="postcards">
                 <?php if ( custom_has_posts($post_type->name) > 0 ) {?>
                     <h4><?php echo $post_type->label; ?></h4>
                 <?php } ?>
              <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <?php if ( $post_type->name == get_post_type() ): ?>
                        <div class="grid__item  postcard">
                            <?php
                            /*
                             * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                             */
                            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
                            ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
              <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

custom_has_posts() function

```
function custom_has_posts($post_type){
   // wp_reset_postdata();
   // $post_query = null;
    //unset($post_query);
   // wp_reset_query();
    $post_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => $post_type, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => $_GET['s'] ) );
    $count =  $post_query->post_count;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    $post_query = null;
    unset($post_query);
    wp_reset_query();
    return $count;
}
```

Comment: Refer to [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts) . You can count posts for custom post type.

Comment: @RohitKishore thank you for your effort, but wp_count_posts does not accepts search term .

Comment: Instead of new WP_Query give get_posts a try.`$results = get_posts($args);
return count($results);`

Comment: @RohitKishore get_posts too does not use search term .

Comment: No it works `$results = get_posts( array( 's' => 'search term' ) );` . http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74763/search-outside-of-the-loop/74766#74766

Comment: @RohitKishore ok, let me try with it.

Comment: @RohitKishore check [get_posts definition](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/post.php#L1369) it does not uses search term.